# Why is "rapid decrease in blood pressure" used more often than "rapid decline in blood pressure"?

Tags: word-difference

There's only a smattering of google-hits for "rapid decline in blood pressure", and significantly more for "rapid decrease in blood pressure".

Is there anything about the nouns 'decline' and 'decrease' that makes the latter preferable, or is it just a coincidence?

[image]

Comment: Numeric measurements usually *increase* and *decrease*. Words like *advance* and *decline* are more situational (Ex: The *decline* and fall of the Roman Empire, a *decline* in one's health). If you check the definitions of [*decline*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=decline) I think you can see this.

Comment: @user3169 - thank you! Judging by the comment upvotes, this is fit for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Decline* and *decrease* both mean *to move down in amount*, but *decline* can also mean *to grow weaker or less desirable.*  For example, a city where businesses are closing and jobs are disappearing can be said to be "in decline" or "declining."  But never "decreasing" unless you specifically say something like "The city's jobs are decreasing."

So *decline* can have a more negative connotation than *decrease*. and thus *decrease* tends to be the more "scientific" or emotionally neutral term.

Telling a patient their blood pressure is "declining" might make them think it will never get back to normal level.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it's more the level excitement and who is actually speaking. When you say the words "rapid decrease" it sounds more excited with the way the word is pronounced. When you say "decline" it make the speaker feel like there is a declining slope. But either works and some people may feel better saying decline than decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric measurements usually increase and decrease. Words like *advance* and *decline* are more situational (Ex: The decline and fall of the Roman Empire, a decline in one's health). If you check the definitions of *[decline](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=decline)* I think you can see this.

Kudos to user3169